# How to submit Azure App Service Quota increase in support request?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I was trying to request Azure App Service Quota limit in US WEST 2 region as I am unable to deploy any App Service plan in Production tab. Becuase I am seeing error related to no quota availabile in that region while create App Service on Azure portal.

I went to open a support request for quota and I could not see any options related to App Service plan quota increase there (see below image).

**So my question is how to submit the Quota increase for Azure App Service in any region and which options to select from the below dropdown?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We need a little more info. There are several possible reasons.

1. There are truly no available instances in this region. I've seen this happen a few times. You just need to check back in a few hours.
2. You're attempting to add a new version of an App Service Plan to an old resource group. When a resource group is provisioned, it's set to a "stamp" that limits the sku's of App Service Plans that can be deployed. The only way to get around this is to create a new resource group and attempt a redeploy. You can tell that you're in this situation if you do so and are able to deploy the App Service Plan sku that you want.

Comment: I have not checked today, but at the time of opening issue I was unable to deploy none of the app service plan in prod category in WEST 2 during that whole day and I tried in different timeslot and multiple time. And several other colleagues and MS customers had same experience in their subscription. And they also could not find quota increase option for App service when creating support ticket.,

Comment: I'm going to guess this is a transient issue. Are you still having the same problems?

Comment: This was issue with one of MS customer who decided to use other approach. In my subscription, I just got error for deploying any app service plan in west 2 region. But it could be due to quota limit on internal MS subscription.